# How to create a dataframe by sampling 1 case (row) from each group in R

Tags: r, sampling

I would like to randomly select 1 case (so 1 row from a dataframe) from each group in R, but I cannot work out how to do it.

My data is structured in longformat: 400 cases (rows) clustered within 250 groups (some groups only contain a single case, others 2, 3, 4, 5, or even 6). So what I would like to end up with is a dataframe containing 250 rows (with each row representing 1 randomly selected case from the 250 different groups).

I have the idea that I should use the sample function for this, but I could work out how to do it. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: One approach is generate a random variable, rank that random variable within groups, and then select out the rank 1 value.

Comment: Randomly permute the rows and extract the first observation in each group.  (This is equivalent to the solution given by @Andy but can be more efficient.)  One way to perform this extraction is to summarize the permuted dataframe by group, retaining the smallest record number within it, and then use those record numbers to index into the permuted dataframe. This kind of solution works in many database environments because it relies only on high-level database operations (sorting, summarizing, selecting).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data frame `X` indicates group membership with a variable named "Group," as in this synthetic example:

```
G <- 8
set.seed(17)
X <- data.frame(Group=sort(sample.int(G, G, replace=TRUE)),
                Case=1:G)
```

Here is a printout of `X`:

> ```
>   Group Case
> 1     2    1
> 2     2    2
> 3     2    3
> 4     4    4
> 5     4    5
> 6     5    6
> 7     7    7
> 8     8    8
> ```

Pick up the first instance of each value of "Group" using the `duplicated` function after randomly permuting the rows of `X`:

```
Y <- X[sample.int(nrow(X)), ]
Y[!duplicated(Y$Group), ]
```

> ```
>   Group Case
> 8     8    8
> 1     2    1
> 4     4    4
> 6     5    6
> 7     7    7
> ```

A comparison to `X` indicates random cases in each group were selected.  Repeat these last two steps to confirm this if you like.